# ¿Cómo obtener todos los objetos espaciales, limitados por un bounding Box, en google maps api?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-v3, google-api

He estado revisando la API de google maps y no he podido encontrar un servicio web que me permita obtener todo lo que tiene google en su base de datos para un bounding-Box en específico.
En esta url: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/?hl=es#places, encontré servicios que me permiten definir un punto y un radio, para luego buscar en ese circulo; pero necesito especificar un bounding-Box y no un circulo.

¿Alguna idea?

Saludos.  mpuebla@uci.cu

Comment: Debieras indicar qué código tienes, qué has intentado, qué resultado esperas obtener y qué estás obteniendo. Revisa [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En el ejemplo que dices aparece una de las maneras de llamar al método `nearbySearch` que es pasándole una ubicación y un radio:

```
service.nearbySearch({
    location: {
        lat: 40.40,
        lng: -3.6955
    },
    radius: 500,
    type: ['store']
}, function (results, status) {
  // acá procesas la respuesta
});
```

Pero la documentación de [google.maps.places.PlacesService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#PlacesService) dice que este método perfectamente puede aceptar en cambio un parámetro `bounds`:

```
service.nearbySearch({
    bounds: {
      south: 40.395,
      west: -3.72,
      north: 40.405,
      east: -3.66
    },
    type: ['store']
}, function (results, status) {
  // acá procesas la respuesta
});
```

```js
function initialize() {
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 9,
  center: {
   lat: 16.959,
   lng: -99.73
  }
 }),
 infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow(),
 service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

  
 function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
   map: map,
   position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
   infowindow.setContent(place.name);
   infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
 }


  var thebounds={
      "south": 16.68408,
      "west": -100.00215,
      "north": 17.23368,
      "east": -99.47364
    };
    map.fitBounds(thebounds);
   
 service.nearbySearch({
  bounds: thebounds
 }, function (results, status) {
  if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
   for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    createMarker(results[i]);
   }
  } else {
    console.log(status);
    }
 });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
#map {
 height:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry,places&key=AIzaSyBRqo4qwqHHrtbY9aL6vYYDw1GOhkK97MQ"></script>
<div id="map">
```

**EDIT**: modifiqué el código acorde a las coordenadas que sugiere el OP.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. No obstante, ejecuté su código con este boundingBox(-100.00215, -99.47364, 16.68408, 17.23368)-- (w,E,S,N)  y con este center: {lat:23.0622222, lng:-82.4213888888889}; también eliminé la restricción del tipo "store", y no obtengo resultado alguno. ¿Será que google no tiene nada en su base de datos para ese cuadrante?, lo dudo. ¿Algún criterio?, ¿nearbySearch retorna realmente todo lo que tiene google en su base de datos? Saludos

Comment: Modifiqué el snippet para usar Acapulco en el centro y funciona bien.

Comment: Ahora sí me funciona. Cometí un error lógico pues puse el bounding-box de Acapulco y el centro en Mariano, Cuba. No obstante, sigo con una duda. No me parece que esos resulatds sea todo lo que tiene google en su base datos. Por ejemplo, veo calles que no salen en los resultados pero están presentes en el mapa de google. ¿Conoce usted alguna forma de extraerle todo a Google? Saludos

Comment: El resultado trae me parece un máximo de 200 elementos, más un paging token, que puedes usar para hacer un nuevo request para los siguientes 200, y así hasta el infinito. Pero sólo obtendrás lo que esté en la base de Places de google, que obviamente es mucho más completa en USA que en latinoamérica

Comment: Con este center  {lat: 23.069534, lng: -82.425920}; y este bounding-box: bounds: { south: 23.0279, west: -82.4438, north: 23.1003, east: -82.3978}, solo obtengo 20 resultados, los conté uno por uno.  ¿Crees que son solo esos o me estoy perdiendo algo que no sé?

Comment: Dices "sólo obtendrás lo que esté en la base de Places de google". De ahí infiero que Google tiene diferentes bases de datos para almacenar el universo de objetos espaciales. Me interesa compararme con Google-Maps en cuanto a la cantidad de objetos espaciales que obtiene para la región del bounding-box que utilicé. ¿Conoce usted alguna forma de extraer todos los objetos espaciales que tiene Google en una región?